# Binding property from MainWindow to TextBlock in MainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I seem to struggle to find answer to my question (I have read lots of them but not a single one worked for me). I'm trying to display some DateTime stored in MainWindow.xaml.cs in TextBlock located on the main window. I was playing with it and so I set up a testing code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DateTime displayTime;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        displayTime = new DateTime(1,1,1,0,1,21,306);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Project1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Main Window" MinHeight="450" Height="450" MinWidth="650" Width="650">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=displayTime, StringFormat='{}{0:h \: m \: ss\.fff}', Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple things to fix.

The first thing is `displayTime` not *property*, it is a *field*. Add getter/setter to make it property accessible for binding.

```
public DateTime displayTime { get; set; }
```

the second thing is `Binding Path=displayTime` binding expect that `displayTime` is a property of DataContext.

try set Window DataContext to self:

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = this;
```

or use relative source in binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=displayTime, 
                  StringFormat='{}{0:h \: m \: ss\.fff}', 
                  Mode=OneWay, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

---

it is fine to bind property from code-behind in a smal view. In a larger view markup and code can get pretty complicated and it is advisable to create a separate *view model* for that view (read about MVVM).

Comment: @Krepsy3, if binding gives trouble check Visual Studio Output window when running the app. VS reports at runtime when bindings are written with mistakes (wrong path, source, type, etc)

Comment: @Krepsy3, Visual Studio Output window